How can these regular polygons be arranged within a page
I have defined regular n-sided polygons, and there’s no issue with outputting them one by one. However,  I would like to arrange several regular n-sided polygons on a single page. Some figures are extending beyond the page margins by running my code. How should I go about doing this?
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% General function: Draw a regular n-sided polygon
\newcommand{\drawPolygon}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{#1} % Set the number of sides
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleStep}{360/\n} % Calculate the step angle for each side
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startAngle}{-90 + \angleStep} % Calculate the starting angle
        % Draw vertices
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {
            \node[draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=2pt] (v\i) at ({\startAngle + (\i - 1) * \angleStep}:2) {};
        }
        % Connect adjacent vertices
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\next}{mod(\i, \n) + 1}
            \draw (v\i) -- (v\next);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach [count=\i] \n in {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} {
        \begin{scope}
            \drawPolygon{\n}
        \end{scope}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Regular 3- to 10-gons}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


I'd like it to be displayed similarly to the website (link), with 3 items per row enter link description here


Another side note is that when I use figure captions, the gap between the caption and the middle of the polygon seems too large.


You don't need tikzpicture to use \foreach. I'd even say that you shouldn't nest tikzpictures.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% General function: Draw a regular n-sided polygon
\newcommand{\drawPolygon}[2][1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{#2} % Set the number of sides
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleStep}{360/\n} % Calculate the step angle for each side
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\startAngle}{-90 + \angleStep} % Calculate the starting angle
    % Draw vertices
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {
      \node[draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=2pt] (v\i) at
        ({\startAngle + (\i - 1) * \angleStep}:2) {};
    }
    % Connect adjacent vertices
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\next}{mod(\i, \n) + 1}
      \draw (v\i) -- (v\next);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\foreach [count=\i] \n in {3, 4, ..., 10} {
  \makebox[0.2\textwidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
      $n=\n$ \\[1ex]
      \drawPolygon[0.5]{\n}
    \end{tabular}%
  }\ifnum\i=4 \\[2ex]\fi
}

\caption{Regular 3- to 10-gons}

\end{figure}

\end{document}

I added an optional argument to \drawPolygon to set a scale.
Each polygon is typeset in a box 20% of the text width; such box contains a top aligned tabular where the first row is the number of sides. After the fourth polygon, a line break (with vertical spacing) is inserted.


Like this?

One way to get above picture is:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 23mm and 7mm,
  start chain = going right,
N/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\i, minimum size=12mm, draw,
            node contents={}}
                    ]
\foreach \i in {3,...,5}%
{
    \node (n1\i)   [N, on chain];
\coordinate[above=3mm of n13] (y);
    \node at (y -| n1\i) {$n=\i$};
}
\foreach \i [count=\j from 3] in {6,...,8}%
{
    \node (n2\j)   [N, below=of y -| n1\j];
\coordinate[above=3mm of n23] (z);
    \node at (z -| n2\j) {$n=\i$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Regular 3- to 8-gons}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}

As you can see, instead of your macro I use regular polygon of shapes.geometric TikZ library.
Edit:
In the case, that shapes should have circles at their corners, than you need to extend above MWE with code lines for example with:
\foreach \c in {1,...,\i} 
    \draw[fill=white] (n1\i.corner \c) circle[radius=2pt];  

Complete WME, now with 10 shapes:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 29mm and 11mm,
  start chain = going right,
N/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\i, minimum size=17mm, draw,
            node contents={}}
                    ]
\foreach \i in {3,...,6}%
{
    \node (n1\i)   [N, on chain];
\coordinate[above=3mm of n13] (y);
    \node at (y -| n1\i) {$n=\i$};
\foreach \c in {1,...,\i} 
    \draw[fill=white] (n1\i.corner \c) circle[radius=2pt];  
}
%
\foreach \i [count=\j from 3] in {7,...,10}%
{
    \node (n2\j)   [N, below=of y -| n1\j];
\coordinate[above=3mm of n23] (z);
    \node at (z -| n2\j) {$n=\i$};
\foreach \c in {1,...,\i} 
    \draw[fill=white] (n2\j.corner \c) circle[radius=2pt];  
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Regular 3- to 10-gons}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}



It is nice yet.

For comparison, here is a Metapost version.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  numeric s, u, v; 
  s = 30; % radius of polygons
  u = 80; % horizontal spacing
  v = -96; % vertical spacing

  numeric rows, cols;
  rows = 2;
  cols = 4;

  pair m; path p; numeric n;
  for r = 0 upto rows - 1:
    for c = 0 upto cols - 1:
      m := (c * u, r * v);
      n := cols * r + c + 3;
      p := (for i=0 upto n-1: s * down rotated (360/n*i) -- endfor cycle);
      p := p shifted m;  % move into position
      

      label.top("$n=" & decimal n & "$", (m + 1.05 s * up));
      draw p withcolor 2/3 red;
      for i=1 upto length p:
        draw point i of p withpen pencircle scaled 3;
        undraw point i of p withpen pencircle scaled 2;
      endfor

    endfor
  endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Compile this with lualatex to get a PDF that looks like this:

Notes
I have made the rows and cols into variables, so you can make bigger or small versions of the table.  You might also like to make them look a bit neater by adjusting each polygon to make them all sit on a common baseline.  To do this add the following just before the line with the comment "move into position".
p := p rotated (-180/n) shifted (0, abs(point 1/2 of p) - s);

With that adjustment and an extra row the picture looks a bit neater (maybe).


I've reproduced egreg's excellent answer using the tkz-elements tool.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mini]{tkz-euclide} 
\usepackage{tkz-elements}

\begin{document}
\directlua{
  z.I      = point:    new (0,0)
  z.A      = point:    new (2,0)
}
\def\drawPolygon#1{
\directlua{
  RP.six   = regular_polygon : new (z.I,z.A,#1)
  RP.six : name ("P_")
  }  
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
 \def\nb{\tkzUseLua{RP.six.nb}}
 \tkzGetNodes
 \tkzDrawCircles(I,A)
 \tkzDrawPolygon(P_1,P_...,P_\nb)
 \tkzDrawPoints[red](P_1,P_...,P_\nb)
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\foreach [count=\i] \n in {3, 4, ..., 10} {
  \makebox[0.2\textwidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
      $n=\n$ \\[1ex]
      \drawPolygon{\n}
    \end{tabular}%
  }\ifnum\i=4 \\[2ex]\fi
}
\caption{Regular 3- to 10-gons}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


